# How to remove queue in Azure Service Bus automatically if no one subscriber do not retrieve messages during month?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm using Azure Service Bus as transport for MassTransit. Now I need to remove  queue automatically if no one subscriber do not retrieve messages during month.
I know about AutoDeleteOnIdle property, but how I can set time for deleting queue if no one subscribers retrieve messages?

May be it's possible to using azure portal(I need to set this for all namespace) or when I create new queue by code?

Comment: Have you looked into Azure resource Manager (ARM) templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AutoDeleteOnIdle` will remove an entity if there's no messages sent/received, not if there's not subscribers.

If your worry is that queue will be accumulating messages, then perhaps switching to a topic/subscription would be better (no subscribers, no messages stored).

As for specifying the value, you could do it from the portal, but I'd first try to do it through the MassTransit API if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure that MassTransit working with topic/subscription, do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Looking at the code - it does. https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/00950d87b10a449e56df796c28175378c8832aa9/src/MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport/Settings/SubscriptionEndpointSettings.cs#L38